# Java: how to playback uncompressed frames

Tags: java, video, media

Given a uncompressed input file with predefined frame format, need to build a simple video player. Could anyone advise where to start? like search keywords, what library to use or examples. Thanks!

For now, I just read all frames and store in linked list which seems not a good idea. Since it should be able to read/playback at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm partial to [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).  See the [MediaTool](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction) part of Xuggler that makes it really easy to write programs using media files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for the Java Media Framework

[Samples you find here:](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/samples/samplecode.html#SimplePlayerApplet)

[and here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/)

Comment: I mean to play frames. say: i have 9999 frames in memory.
BufferedImage img[9999];

Is there any library can play this and set different playback speed? Thanks.

Comment: Just google "bufferedimage display" this provides you a plenty of code examples. Simply use a timer to change speed (don't forget to upvote ;-)

Comment: End up by using JFrame and JLabel.setIcon.